# Objective-C Protocols

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, class, protocols

I came across the following bit of code in a file called TileOverlay.h:

```
@protocol TileOverlay <MKOverlay>
```

I'm trying to understand explicitly what this is doing.  Several other overlays then import this .h file.  Does this file essentially just create a modified version of the MKOverlay class?

If not, can you please clarify what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called protocol inheritance.

`MKOverlay` is a protocol, defining a set of methods for objects to implement.

`TileOverlay` inherits for `MKOverlay`, meaning that an object conforming to `TileOverlay`, should implement methods from `MKOverlay` and methods from `TileOverlay`

[Here](http://mobileorchard.com/idprotocol-retainrelease-and-protocol-inheritance/) is a link that talks a little bit more about protocol inheritance

Answer (score 5):

`MKOverlay` is a protocol, and `TileOverlay` is a protocol that extends `MKOverlay`.

Any class that conforms to the `TileOverlay` protocol also conforms to the `MKOverlay` protocol.

Refer to [Protocols Within Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF152) in the documentation for a detailed explanation.

Comment: How does a protocol differ from a regular class, then?

Comment: Protocols are interfaces with no implementation.  A class can conform to a protocol to advertise that it supports the functionality of the protocol.   Think of it as multiple inheritance for interfaces.

Comment: [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1) declare methods that can be implemented by classes

Answer (score 1):

You can think of protocols like interfaces in Java or C#, basically they declare a contract that the implementing classes must follow. The difference is that in Objective C you can make some of the declared methods optional.

Answer (score 0):

A protocol in Objective-C is what you in Java or C# would call an interface. It is a contract that any other class can fulfill, in Obj-C parlance *conform to*.

This:

```
@protocol TileOverlay <MKOverlay>
```

Defines a protocol named `TileOverlay` that in itself extends `MKOverlay`. That is by conforming to `TileOverlay` you must also conform to `MKOverlay`.

Protocols in Obj-C, just as interfaces in Jave or C#, is not related to implementation. It does not do anything. It's just a marker at compile time, and at run-time if you want to, to check if some functionally exist.

Comment: There is, IMO, one significant difference between Java and C# interfaces and Objective-C protocols though: protocols can (and often do) have optional methods. This is not possible in Java or C#, AFAIK.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis - Very true, and a **VERY** useful feature of Obj-C protocols.